# Why should I return Task<IActionResult> in a Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

So I have been trying to get the grasp for quite some time now but couldn't see the sense in declaring every controller-endpoint as an async method.

Let's look at a GET-Request to visualize the question.

This is my way to go with simple requests, just do the work and send the response.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetUsers()
{
      // Do some work and get a list of all user-objects.
      List<User> userList = _dbService.ReadAllUsers(); 
      return Ok(userList);
}
```

Below is the `async Task<IActionResult>` option I see very often, it does the same as the method above but the method itself is returning a `Task`. One could think, that this one is better because you can have multiple requests coming in and they get worked on asynchronously BUT I tested this approach and the approach above with the same results. Both can take multiple requests at once. So why should I choose this signature instead of the one above? I can only see the negative effects of this like transforming the code into a state-machine due to being async.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers()
{
      // Do some work and get a list of all user-objects.
      List<User> userList = _dbService.ReadAllUsers(); 
      return Ok(userList);
}
```

This approach below is also something I don't get the grasp off. I see a lot of code having exactly this setup. One `async` method they `await` and then returning the result. Awaiting like this makes the code sequential again instead of having the benefits of Multitasking/Multithreading. Am I wrong on this one?

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers()
{
      // Do some work and get a list of all user-objects.
      List<User> userList = await _dbService.ReadAllUsersAsync(); 
      return Ok(userList);
}
```

It would be nice if you could enlighten me with facts so I can either continue developing like I do right now or know that I have been doing it wrong due to misunderstanding the concept.

Comment: becuase async operation returns a task, which its result won't be availble till the task is completed.

Comment: Actually you should look at it this way: When you make a task based method, you are essentially saying that your method is using some asynchronous operations. It has nothing to do with the caller per se. The caller only knows that it should await the operation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please read the ["Synchronous vs. Asynchronous Request Handling" section of Intro to Async/Await on ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net#synchronous-vs-asynchronous-request-handling).

> Both can take multiple requests at once.

Yes. This is because ASP.NET is multithreaded. So, in the synchronous case, you just have multiple threads invoking the same action method (on different controller instances).

For non-multithreaded platforms (e.g., Node.js), you *have* to make the code asynchronous to handle multiple requests in the same process. But on ASP.NET it's optional.

> Awaiting like this makes the code sequential again instead of having the benefits of Multitasking/Multithreading.

Yes, it is *sequential*, but it's not *synchronous*. It's *sequential* in the sense that the `async` method executes one statement at a time, and that request isn't complete until the `async` method completes. But it's not *synchronous* - the synchronous code is also sequential, but it *blocks a thread* until the method completes.

> So why should I choose this signature instead of the one above?

**If** your backend can scale, then the benefit of asynchronous action methods is scalability. Specifically, asynchronous action methods yield their thread while the asynchronous operation is in progress - in this case, `GetUsers` is not taking up a thread while the database is performing its query.

The benefit can be hard to see in a testing environment, because your server has threads to spare, so there's no observable difference between calling an asynchronous method 10 times (taking up 0 threads) and calling a synchronous method 10 times (taking up 10 threads, with another 54 to spare). You can [artificially restrict the number of threads in your ASP.NET server and then do some tests](https://gist.github.com/StephenCleary/5796697) to see the difference.

In a real-world server, you usually want to make it as asynchronous as possible so that your threads are available for handling *other* requests. Or, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net#why-not-increase-the-thread-pool-size):

> Bear in mind that asynchronous code does not replace the thread pool. This isn’t thread pool **or** asynchronous code; it’s thread pool **and** asynchronous code. Asynchronous code allows your application to make optimum use of the thread pool. It takes the existing thread pool and turns it up to 11.

Bear in mind the "**if**" above; this particularly applies to existing code. If you have just a single SQL server backend, and if pretty much all your actions query the db, then changing them to be asynchronous [may not be useful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net#asynchronous-code-is-not-a-silver-bullet), since the scalability bottleneck is usually the db server and not the web server. But if your web app could use threads to handle non-db requests, or if your db backend is scalable (NoSQL, SQL Azure, etc), then changing action methods to be asynchronous would likely help.

For new code, I recommend asynchronous methods by default. Asynchronous makes better use of server resources and is more cloud-friendly (i.e., less expensive for pay-as-you-go hosting).

Comment: @ZesaRex: [No](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net#what-about-the-thread-doing-the-asynchronous-work). `ReadAllUsersAsync` sends the query to the database *and then returns* an incomplete task. When that task is `await`ed, the thread returns to the thread pool and can handle other requests while the db is executing the query.

Comment: @ZesaRex: The asynchronous equivalent of `Thread.Sleep` is `await Task.Delay`, which does not block a thread. If you are talking about real-world code that uses `async` without `await`, then there will be a compiler warning informing you that the method will actually run synchronously.

Comment: Good, that translates to a "yes" to my question! :) thanks

Answer (score 4):

If your DB Service class has an `async` method for getting the user then you should see benefits. As soon as the request goes out to the DB then it is waiting on a network or disk response back from the service at the other end. While it is doing this the thread can be freed up to do other work, such as servicing other requests. As it stands in the non-async version the thread will just block and wait for a response.

With `async` controller actions you can also get a `CancellationToken` which will allow you to quit early if the token is signalled because the client at the other end has terminated the connection (but that may not work with all web servers).

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers(CancellationToken ct)
{
    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    // Do some work and get a list of all user-objects.
    List<User> userList = await _dbService.ReadAllUsersAsync(ct); 
    return Ok(userList);
}
```

So, if you have an expensive set of operations and the client disconnects, you can stop processing the request because the client won't ever receive it. This frees up the application's time and resources to deal with requests where the client is interested in a result coming back.

However, if you have a very simple action that requires no `async` calls then I probably wouldn't worry about it, and leave it as it is.

Comment: A very good point mentioning operation cancellation using `CancellationToken`. I think it would be helpful if you expand a bit more on the concept and why it is helpful in your answer as it will serve as a great piece of information on the current topic.

Answer (score 2):

As you know, ASP.NET is based on a multi-threaded model of request execution. To put it simply, each request is run in its own thread, contrary to other single thread execution approaches like the event-loop in nodejs.

Now, threads are a finite resource. If you exhaust your thread pool (available threads) you can't continue handling tasks efficiently (or in most cases at all). If you use synchronous execution for your action handlers, you occupy those threads from the pool (even if they don't need to be). It is important to understand that those threads handle requests, they **don't do** input/output. I/O is handled by separate processes which are independent of the ASP.NET request threads. So, if in your action you have a DB fetch operation that takes let's say 15 seconds to execute, you're forcing your current thread to wait **idle** 15 seconds for the DB result to be returned so it can continue executing code. Therefore, if you have 50 such requests, you'll have 50 threads occupied in basically sleep mode. Obviously, this is not very scalable and becomes a problem soon enough. In order to use your resources efficiently, it is a good idea to preserve the state of the executing request when an I/O operation is reached and free the thread to handle another request in the meantime. When the I/O operation completes, the state is reassembled and given to a free thread in the pool to resume the handling. That's why you use async handling. It lets you use your finite resources more efficiently and prevents such thread starvation. Of course, it is not an ultimate solution. It helps you scale your application for higher load. If you don't have the need for it, don't use it as it just adds overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing something fundamental here.

When you use `async Task<>` you are effectively saying, "run all the I/O code asynchronously and free up processing threads to... process".

At scale, your app will be able to serve more requests/second because your I/O is not tying up your CPU intensive work and vice versa.

You're not seeing much benefit now, because you're probably testing locally with plenty of resources at hand.

See

- [Understanding CPU and I/O bound for asynchronous operations](https://www.hellsoft.se/understanding-cpu-and-i-o-bound-for-asynchronous-operations/)
- [Async in depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/async-in-depth)

Comment: Your first example ties up a thread. Your second example won't compile because there's no `await`. The third example will scale as long as there's no backend bottleneck. And, yes, I have tested this kind of scenario.

Comment: Thanks. The second example by the way actually compiles. It will just be treated as sync.

Comment: Doh. You're right. I'm used to seeing that red squiggly underline in the IDE and just adding the `async`. I have warnings set as errors.

Answer (score 0):

Async operations return a Task(it is not the result, but a promise made that will have the results once the task is completed.

The async methods should be `await`ed so that it waits till the task is completed. if you `await` an async method, the return values won't be a task anymore and will be the results you expected.

Imagine this async method:

```
async Task<SomeResult> SomeMethod()
{
    ...
}
```

the following code:

```
var result = SomeMethod(); // the result is a Task<SomeResult> which may have not completed yet

var result = await SomeMethod(); // the result is type of SomeResult
```

Now, why do we use `async` methods instead of sync methods:

Imagine that a Method is doing some job that may take a long time to complete, when it is done sync all other requests will be waiting till the execution of this long taking job to complete, as they are all happening in the same thread. However when it is async, the task will be done in a (possibly another) thread and will not block the other requests.

Comment: because async operations does not block you other codes and run in another thread. let me update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The result returns a task from an asynchronous (non-blocking) operation which represents some work that should be done. The task can tell you if the work is completed and if the operation returns a result, the task gives you the result which won't be available until the task is completed. You can learn more about C# asynchronous programming from the official Microsoft Docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=net-5.0