# Make all conroller methods async easy way

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web api with controller methods being like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage DoSmth() {
    doingSmth();
}
```

I've read about how server threads here: [Why should I return Task<IActionResult> in a Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66816361/why-should-i-return-taskiactionresult-in-a-controller)
and here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net#synchronous-vs-asynchronous-request-handling

The implementation of business\data access layers is syncronous (and **huge**) and there is no time left to refactor everything into `async task<>`.
Is there some way to refactor only the controller, i.e. "topmost" methods into being asyncronous so server won't run out of threads?

Comment: Have you read about Task.Run()?

Comment: @AdamB clearly OP read about it and know that using Task.Run in ASP.Net will only cause more scalability problems by consuming more threads. I hope that is exactly what you wanted to warn OP about.

Comment: Ah sorry I guess I misunderstood the question. I guess I’ll leave it here as it seems it might be useful! >_<

Comment: "cause more scalability problems by consuming more threads." - yes, and it is the opposite of what I need. I cant't  bll\dal into task, I just want the controller methods to be tasks themselves. Or is there something I'm not getting right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some way to refactor only the controller, i.e. "topmost" methods into being asyncronous so server won't run out of threads?

No.

You can think of it this way: synchronous calls block a thread. As long as your business logic / DAL methods are synchronous, they will block a thread.

As some have noted in the comments, `Task.Run` will allow those methods to block a thread pool thread instead of the calling thread, and that's a fine approach for many GUI apps (block thread pool threads instead of the GUI thread), but it's counterproductive on server apps (block one thread pool thread instead of another thread pool thread).

I recommend first analyzing your app and determining which requests are the slowest or most frequently called, and changing just those to be `async` all the way. You can use the [flag argument hack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development#the-flag-argument-hack) (attribution: me) to avoid code duplication in your logic/DAL types when creating asynchronous equivalents of synchronous methods.